# R Shiny Dashboard - Loading Scripts using source('file.R')

Tags: r, shiny, include, shinydashboard

**Introduction**

I have created an R shiny dashboard app that is quickly getting quite complex.  I have over 1300 lines of code all sitting in app.R and it works.  I'm using RStudio.

My application has a sidebar and tabs and rather than using modules I dynamically grab the siderbar and tab IDs to generate a unique identifier when plotting graphs etc.

I'm trying to reorganise it to be more manageable and split it into tasks for other programmers but I'm running into errors.

**Working Code**

My original code has a number of library statements and sets the working directory to the code location.

```
rm(list = ls())
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
getwd()
```

I then have a range of functions that sit outside the ui/server functions so are only loaded once (not reactive).  These are all called from within the server by setting the reactive values and calling the functions from within something like a renderPlot.  Some of them are nested, so a function in server calls a function just in regular app.R which in turn calls another one.  Eg.

```
# Start of month calculation
som <- function(x) {
  toReturn <- as.Date(format(x, "%Y-%m-01"))
  return(toReturn)
}

start_fc <- function(){
  fc_start_date <- som(today())
  return(fc_start_date)
}
```

then in server something like this (code incomplete)

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  RV <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    RV$selection <- input[[input$sidebar]]
  #  cat("Selected:",RV$selection,"\r")
  })
  
.......
    cat(paste0("modelType: ",input[[paste0(RV$selection,"-modeltype")]]," \n"))
    vline1 <- decimal_date(start_pred(input[[paste0(RV$selection,"-modeltype")]],input[[paste0(RV$selection,"-modelrange")]][1]))
    vline2 <- decimal_date(start_fc())
.......
```

**Problem Code**

So now when I take all my functions and put them into different .R files I get errors indicating the functions haven't been loaded.  If I load the source files by highlighting them and Alt-Enter running them so they are loaded into memory then click on Run App the code works.  But if I rely on Run App to load those source files, and the functions within them, the functions can't be found.

```
source('./functionsGeneral.R')
source('./functionsQuote.R')
source('./functionsNewBusiness.R')

source('./ui.R')
source('./server.R')

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

where ui.R is

```
source('./header.R')
source('./sidebar.R')
source('./body.R')

source('./functionsUI.R')

ui <- dashboardPage( 
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

**Finally the questions**

In what order does R Shiny Dashboard run the code.  Why does it fail when I put the exact same inline code into another file and reference it with source('./functions.R')?  Does it not load into memory during a shiny app session?  What am I missing?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Travis

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've discovered the easiest way is to create a subfolder called R and to place the preload code into that folder.  From shiny version 1.5 all this code in the R folder is loaded first automatically.